# I keep getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am currently working on my add-to-cart controller, Am I missing anything that's why it won't work? It seems like my "cartItems" is not defined, How do I define this? Apologies I'm a beginner. I have the following under my /controller/cart:

```
const Cart = require('../models/cart');

exports.addItemToCart = (req, res) => {

    Cart.find({ user: req.user._id})
    .exec( (error, cart) => {
        if(error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
        if(cart){
            //if cart already exists then update cart by quantity

            const product = req.body.cartItems.product;
            const item = cart.cartItems.find(c => c.product == product); //ERROR OCCURS HERE//

            if(item){

                Cart.findOneAndUpdate({ user: req.user._id, "cartItems.product": product}, {
                    "$set": {
                        "cartItems": {
                            ...req.body.cartItems,
                            quantity: item.quantity + req.body.cartItems.quantity
                        }
                    }
                })
                .exec( ( error, _cart) => {
                    if(error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
                    if(_cart){
                        return res.status(201).json({ cart: _cart})
                    }
                })

            } else {
                Cart.findOneAndUpdate({ user: req.user._id }, {
                    "$push": {
                        "cartItems": req.body.cartItems
                    }
                })
                .exec( ( error, _cart) => {
                    if(error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
                    if(_cart){
                        return res.status(201).json({ cart: _cart})
                    }
                })
            }

           

        } else {
            //if cart does not exist then create a new cart
            const cart = new Cart({
                user: req.user._id,
                cartItems: [req.body.cartItems]
            });

            cart.save( (error, cart) => {
                if(error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
                if(cart){
                    return res.status(201).json({ cart });
                }
            }); 
        }
    });

}
```

my schema for cart are as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    cartItems: [
        {
            product: { 
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Product',
                required: true
            },
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                default: 1
            },
            price: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            }
        }
    ]
}, { timestamps: true });


module.exports = mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema);
```

When I try to run a post request in postman with this:

```
{
    "cartItems": {
        "product": "611d12946c14c2232c933af8",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 7000
    }
}
```

I get this error on my gitbash:

```
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at cart.js:12:41
```

Comment: Your `cart` is an array. If you want an object, use `Cart.findOne(...` instead.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc I've tried this one as well but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

is your `_id` defined?  doesn't look like it from the user structure.  I would add a `console.log(req)` right before that line 12, so you can see what is in the inbound parameter, and identify which piece(s) are missing from your handler's assumptions.